# include rendered html template in json

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views

I'd like to include my rendered html template into a json object.

```
def updates(request, game_id, from_staff_comment_id):
    game = Game.objects.latest()
    staff_comments = StaffComment.objects.find_by_game_with(game_id, from_staff_comment_id)
    staff_comments_max = 0
    if staff_comments:
        staff_comments_max = staff_comments[0].id
    game_json = {
        'home_score': game.home_score,
        'guest_score': game.guest_score,
        #'staff_comments': serializers.serialize('json', staff_comments, fields=('time', 'unsername', 'comment')),
        'staff_comments_html': render_to_string('live_staff_comment.html', {'comments': staff_comments}),
        'staff_comments_max': staff_comments_max
    }
    return HttpResponse(simplejson.dumps(game_json), mimetype='application/json')
```

`render_to_string()` works but the html is escaped so it renders as text when I append it to the browser using javascript.

Can you help me ?

Thanks

Comment: Is there a reason why you are not rendering the template directly instead of converting it in to a json object first

Comment: What do you mean "is escaped"? Do you mean that instead of `<` you have `&lt;`, etc? Or json encoding escapes the HTML?

Comment: my bad, I had a line return between '<' and 'span' so the html in my template wasn't valid.

Comment: I needed HTML in json because I need some raw data AND some html fragments to inject via ajax and append() so I don't have to render it browser side.